# TypeScript, Angular 2 Dependency Injection with Inheritance

Tags: inheritance, dependency-injection, typescript, angular

I am using Angular 2 with TypeScript to construct a front end application. I have a Generic Repository class:

```
export abstract class Repository<T extends IEntity>
{    
  constructor(protected _http: Http) {}

  add(entity: T) {}
  delete(entity: T) {}
  list() {}
  get(id: number) {} 
  update(entity: T) {}
}
```

My Service class then extends my Generic Repository Class:

```
export class Service extends Repository<Entity>
{    
  constructor(protected _http: Http) {
    super(Http);
  }
}
```

The problem arises when I use dependency injection in the Parent class. How do I then translate that to the child class?

When TypeScript compiles i get the following error:

> error TS2345: Argument of type 'typeof Http' is not assignable to
>   parameter of type 'Http'.Property '_backend' is missing in type
>   'typeof Http'

Im not sure how to correct this error. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You just need to forward the instance you get passed (instead of the type as you did):

```
export class Service extends Repository<Entity>
{    
  constructor(protected _http: Http) {
    super(_http);
  }
}
```

If no additional parameters are introduced in the subclass and also no additional code needs to be executed in the subclasses constructor, you can just omit the constructor.

Comment: Thank you. May I ask a small follow up question. Does the child class inherit any classes that the parent class imports. For instance. The parent class imports http, response and headers. Do I have to import that into the parent class or no. Because it seems i get an error when I don t import http. error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Http'. Is that just because i have to pass on the dependency or do I have to to that will all the classes rxjs, response, headers etc?

Comment: If the subclass is in a different file you need to import every class or other identifier you refer to in your code. If you use `X` somewhere in one of your `*.ts` file (where `X` is the name of a class that is declared in another file) you have to import that class to make it known inside your file. Not too easy to explain. Keep the follow-up questions coming if this doesn't make it clear ;-)

Comment: What if _http needs to be private a private member of the parent so that child constructor takes no parameters?

Comment: @Shawn What do mean with parent? The super class? This is not possible. If you extend a class the sub class needs to provide the parameters for the super class. That's not related to Angular2 but TS only and similar in most class based languages.